# Auto set image height and width based on image size

Tags: html, css

So I often export images from photoshop into PNG and into a webpage. I always have to manually type `width: 100 height 100` and go up until I full reach the size of the image.

How can I automatically set the image height and width based on how big the image already is.

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="client">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="page_bg">
                <div class="welcome-card">
                    <div class="card">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome-card{
    background-image:url("../images/welcome-card.png");
    height:400px;
    width:360px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

It looks like this https://i.gyazo.com/74c78f9cb79c195701d24ffb77abeec7.png

I keep adjusting the `width` and `height` until i fully reveal the image. Is there a faster way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `img` tag instead of using the image as a background image in a `div` element

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.welcome-card{
  background-image:url("../images/welcome-card.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Note that you still need to set the height and width of the .welcome-card element to whatever you want the final size to be.

To make it more clear why this is important to know, I made this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGmMJz

Notice that the original image is 768x1024px. Using responsive layout, its easy to adjust the width and height of each cell without caring about the underlying dimensions of the background image just by using cover and background-position: center.

As you change the browser width, notice how everything moves around with no extra work needed. Most of your styling is at the smallest dimension and you just tweak certain properties as the width expands.

Comment: I don't understand this. So if I still have to set the height and width, then it's basically the same as what I had previously.

Comment: No, its not the same thing. background-size: cover and object-fit: cover are the secret sauce to auto scaling images in responsive web design.

Comment: Ah I see. I was not aware. Thanks

Comment: @JordanBrown Updated the answer with an example for you to look at.

Comment: Thank you so much. This sort of thing is very important. Thank you for taking the time to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

try use this

object-fit: cover;

Comment: This works, but since he's using background-image its better to use background-size: cover. object-fit: cover is useful if its an img or picture element for example.